# Subtract current rows second element from the next rows first element in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have 6x2 numpy array. I want to subtract current rows second element from the next rows first element and get the new column. 
Currently i'm using for loop to do that. 
Ex:

```
from numpy import array
a = array([[1,3],
           [2,5],
           [6,7],
           [8,9],
           [5,6],
           [6,9]])
k = []
for i in range(a.shape[0]-1):
    k.append(a[i][1]-a[i+1][0])
array(k)
```

`Output : [1, -1, -1, 4, 0]`

How can I get the same output using numpy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slice and subtract -

```
a[1:,0] - a[:-1,1]
```

Sample run -

```
In [303]: a
Out[303]: 
array([[1, 3],
       [2, 5],
       [6, 7],
       [8, 9],
       [5, 6],
       [6, 9]])

In [304]: a[1:,0] - a[:-1,1]
Out[304]: array([-1,  1,  1, -4,  0])
```

Since, we have two columns only, another way/trick would be to use differentiaton on flattened version and then step into every other element starting from the second element -

```
In [308]: np.diff(a.ravel())[1::2]
Out[308]: array([-1,  1,  1, -4,  0])
```